# How to protect an iPhone 4s from Internet access?

Tags: security, iphone, ios

Is there a way to disable/lock the Wi-Fi network access on an iPhone 4S?  Crazy question, I know.  But I got my son an iPhone and do not want him to have an Internet access. I disabled his data through my account with Sprint.  But with Wi-Fi he can still get on the Internet when he is within reach of open hotspots (we do not have open Wi-Fi at home).

I want to be able to disable the Wi-Fi capabilities of his iPhone so that he cannot access the Internet.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is worrying a lot of parents :(.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to do this directly on iOS. What you can do that is the closest thing to what you want to achieve is to follow these steps:

- Go to Settings > General > Restrictions > Enable Restrictions and create a passcode that only you will know (and it should be different from the passcode that has been set on your son's iPhone, if there is one).
- Then deselect the following items: Safari, iTunes Store, iBookstore, Installing Apps, Deleting Apps, in-App Purchases, Siri, and FaceTime (of course, deselect whatever you see fit, but my example is an extreme example).

[image]

- On the same Restrictions menu, go to Accounts and tap "Don't Allow Changes".

[image]

- Go to Restrictions once again, and go to Cellular Data Use and tap "Don't Allow Changes".

[image]

- Finally, go back to Restrictions, scroll down to the bottom of the page, and tap the following switches under Game Center: "Multiplayer Games" and "Adding Friends."

[image]

I'm assuming that you don't want your son to use any form of Internet on the iPhone AT ALL. This will limit the iPhone to the most limited form as possible. I can't guarantee that your son will not be able to use the Internet in some way, shape, or form, but at least you have now severely limited the chances.